# Why this webpage put the whole HTML body inside a <form>? What does it do?

Tags: html, forms

I occasionally found this website:

https://sudoku.com.au/

It puts all of its key HTML elements inside a `<form>` tag:

Why? What's the meaning or benefit out of this?

[image]

Comment: You should ask the creator of the website for the meaning to put all of the body into a form...

Answer (score 2):

It will allow it, once you press submit, the sudoku numbers will just be submitted to the computer, then will be read if correct, then submitted to whatever database or server to keep those stuff.It, Im pretty sure has a leaderboard, so it will just look for the highest thing in the database.

Ask me for any questions.